# Help Implement Tags in PHP

Tags: php, tags, xss

In my recent PHP project, I need to implement Tags (searchable) separated by comma (similar to this site or something like in WordPress). What is the smart way to detect and remove unnecessary characters or tags? Putting the XSS concern aside, first of all I need to clean and extract only text if user inputs HTML(or other tags) instead of the plain text.

For example:

```
If user inputs <b>sdfasdf</b>, <a href="something">sdfsdfsdf</a>, <sdfsdfsdf
It should strip out all the unnecessary characters and tags and only plain text should be saved in database.
```

I have tried it in WordPress and it is very smart to figure out this plus automatically extracts text only.

My question:

Is there an open source library available for this task, which I can integrate in my project. I have done some homework regarding this but ***htmlentities(), strip_tags(), HTML Purifier*** etc. doesn't seem suitable for this task. Or do need to build my own library combined with this?

Can somebody guide me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't `strip_tag` seem suitable for this task?

Comment: because it seems `strip_tag` cannot remove the incomplete or broken tags

Comment: If WordPress seems to do what you're looking for, I would suggest looking at how they handle it and reproduce a similar method.

Comment: On one hand, you want to allow user to input HTML, but on the other hand, it might not be HTML? I'd keep it simple stupid and make users enter coma separated tags, not HTML. But I don't know your use case.

Comment: Why not just only allow alphanumeric tags?

Comment: @Michail I thought of just disallowing ">", "<" characters but tag is allowed in international language (backend db is utf8-unicode collated). I am not just sure if I can do this with regex.

Comment: UPDATE - my basic experiment seems ok but still ugly. Since I am not sure about international language, initially everything is allowed. With the help of 'urlencode', 'urldecode', 'stripcslahes' and 'htmlentities' I was able to show the tags even if it has markup. Clicking on tag (which is hyperlinked), I can search the tag in database and display the similar entries with particular tags. But it still looks ugly. One of my tag looks like this: [ <a href=\"sdfdf\">kdjfldkfj</a> dfsdfsdf  • dfdfff  ]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing "complete" tags (markup language elements) such as found in `<b>sdfasdf</b>, <a href="something">sdfsdfsdf</a>`, 
you can also remove "forbidden" characters such as "<", ">", and "&" (using `preg_replace` and the like), and collapse multiple spaces into a single space (also using `preg_replace`). 
Remember, they're used only as tags (keywords), so it's acceptable here to use a somewhat restricted character set.  In Stack
Overflow, for instance, only letters, numbers, and hyphens are allowed in tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this the other way around. What input is legal? Which characters are allowed in tag names? Ones those questions are answered I would build a server-side whitelist of legal characters using regex, state the rules in the UI, and simply reject input that does comply.

Massaging invalid inpu into valid, is rarely a good idea.

Characters allowed in tags are usually alphanumeric + dashes and underscores. Some sites also allow spaces.

Comment: My backend is utf8-unicode collated and international languages are allowed. I not sure if it can be filtered out with regex. Thank for advise